# SELECT list expression references oregon.count_or which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Tags: sql, subquery

I want 3 columns from this data table (bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current). Year, sum of children born with the name Declan in the state of OR and the sum of children named Declan in the USA grouped by year. I could do this in 2 separate queries but trying to do it in 1.

I created a temporary table  and created a count_or column in that table so I could filter just on the state. When I call this column in the second SELECT I get the "select list expression neither grouped nor aggregated" error. I know I'm wrong but dont know how to get around it.

WITH oregon
AS
(SELECT year, SUM(number) AS count_or
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
Where name = 'Declan' and state = 'OR'
GROUP BY year)
SELECT oregon.year, count_or, SUM(number) AS count_country
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
FULL JOIN `oregon`  ON 'bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current.year' = 'oregon.year'
WHERE name = 'Declan'
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to join the results of the first query (count for Declan in Oregon) with the total count for Declan in the USA. You are having problems because you are referencing the count_or column in the SELECT list without grouping or aggregating.

Your query can be modified as follows:

```
WITH oregon AS (
SELECT year, SUM(number) AS count_or
FROM bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current
WHERE name = 'Declan' and state = 'OR'
GROUP BY year
)

SELECT
COALESCE(oregon.year, usa.year) AS year,
COALESCE(count_or, 0) AS count_or,
COALESCE(SUM(number), 0) AS count_country

FROM
oregon
FULL JOIN
bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current usa
ON
usa.year = oregon.year AND usa.name = 'Declan'

GROUP BY
year, count_or
ORDER BY
year;
```

COALESCE function to handle NULL values that might result from the outer join and, aliases (Oregon and USA) to differentiate between the two instances of the usa_1910_current table. Also, COALESCE(count_or, 0) to handle the case where there is no match in the Oregon CTE.